# What case is to be made when the Dividend and the Divisor have a value of zero?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting a divided by zero error on my Query even after adding a case to make the values null. I think it may be because a.grosspcs is also a value of zero at the first of the month. However, I tried this case every which way for the last 2 hours and it keeps coming up. Am I missing something? Do I need the case in the CTE select statements also? If a.grosspcs is also a value of zero do I make 2 cases?I am still new to SQL so thanks in advance for any help.

```
SELECT datename(MM,a.MonthDate) as Month 

,Sum(a.ScrapPcs) / (Sum(a.GrossPcs)*1.00) As ScrapPct

,0.005 As ScrapTarget

,CASE 
 WHEN Sum(a.ScrapPcs) / (Sum(a.GrossPcs)*1.00) <= 0.005 THEN 1
 WHEN Sum(a.ScrapPcs) / (Sum(a.GrossPcs)*1.00) >= 0.9*.005 THEN -1
 ELSE 0
 END 
 AS Status

,Case
  when a.ScrapPcs=0 then null
Else a.GrossPcs / a.ScrapPcs
 end 

FROM 
(
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, b.CreationProdDate), 0) As MonthDate
      ,Count(b.BOOKING_ID) As ScrapPcs
      , 0 As GrossPcs

FROM dbo.CPC_BOOKING b

WHERE b.CreationProdDate Between DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GetDate()), 0) AND DateAdd("d", -1, GetDate())
AND CPC_Level_ID = 37

GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, b.CreationProdDate), 0)

UNION ALL 


SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, n.date), 0) As MonthDate
      ,0 As ScrapPcs
      ,Sum(n.Processed) As GrossPcs

 FROM [NORIS].[dbo].[USC_CustomerCounts] n

WHERE n.date Between DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GetDate()), 0) AND DateAdd("d", -1, GetDate())
and n.Customer = 'SGM'

GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, n.Date), 0)
) a

group by a.MonthDate,a.GrossPcs, a.ScrapPcs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the divisors in a `NULLIF()` function

```
  SELECT 100 / NULLIF( val ,0)  AS foo
--             ^^^^^^^     ^^^
```

---

In the first SELECT, I see four division operations

The fourth one, inside the CASE statement...  I don't think there's any guarantee that SQL Server won't evaluate the contents of the `ELSE` before it evaluates the condition in the `WHEN`.

change this, where the order of operations is not guaranteed:

```
  , Case
    when a.ScrapPcs=0 then null
    Else a.GrossPcs / a.ScrapPcs
    end
```

to this

```
  , a.GrossPcs / NULLIF( a.ScrapPcs ,0)
    --           ^^^^^^^            ^^^
```

so the `NULLIF` function is guaranteed to be evaluated before the division. (The division can't be performed before the value to divide by is known.)

Also, if there's no guarantee that `Sum(a.GrossPcs)` won't ever be zero, then 
wrap that expression in a `NULLIF` where it's used as a divisor. (Or, wrap the whole divisor in a `NULLIF`.) I see three occurrences of that expression in the SELECT list which would have a "divide by zero".

```
    foo  / ( NULLIF( SUM(a.GrossPcs) ,0)*1.00 )
         --  ^^^^^^^                 ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Ive been falling behind on other work trying to figure this out

Comment: note: `NULLIF(a,b)` is shorthand for `CASE WHEN a  = b THEN NULL  ELSE a END`

Comment: Just to be sure, it should look something like this


SELECT datename(MM,a.MonthDate) as Month 

,Sum(a.ScrapPcs) / ( NULLIF( SUM(a.GrossPcs) ,0)*1.00 ) As ScrapPct

,0.005 As ScrapTarget

,CASE 
 WHEN Sum(a.ScrapPcs) / ( NULLIF( SUM(a.GrossPcs) ,0)*1.00 ) <= 0.005 THEN 1
 WHEN Sum(a.ScrapPcs) / ( NULLIF( SUM(a.GrossPcs) ,0)*1.00 ) >= 0.9*.005 THEN -1
 ELSE 0
 END 
 AS Status

 ,a.GrossPcs / NULLIF( a.ScrapPcs ,0)

Comment: yes, that looks like what I suggested. As an alternative, with longer, more complicated divisor expressions  `SELECT foo /  ( hugh_jass_expression )` we can wrap that entire expression in a NULLIF function...  `SELECT foo / NULLIF( ( hugh_jass_expression ) ,0)`